# Difference between structural and non-structural for lists

Tags: kotlin

As described in Kotlin documentation, particularily List::subList method [docs](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-list/sub-list.html):

> The returned list is backed by this list, so **non-structural** changes in the returned list are reflected in this list, and vice-versa.
>
> **Structural** changes in the base list make the behavior of the view undefined.

I was not able to find any further explanation nor exact definition of the above mentioned structural and non-structural change. The intuition would be as follows:

---

**Non-structural**

Changing elements of the list, not the list itself. For example, changing value of the first element of the list from `1` to `2`. Another example would be casting the list to other type.

**Structural:**

Changing the list structure: deleting or adding elements, changing elements' order.

---

My question primarily is: are my assumptions correct? Can we add something to these 'definitions'?

What about **structural** changes in the returned sub-list, do they make the base list view undefined? And finally, does *undefined* mean that changes in the base or sub-list **may or may not** be reflected in the corresponding views?

Thanks in advance for the discussion and your insight!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the same method as [the Java version](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/List.html#subList-int-int-) and its documentation answers your questions (technically Kotlin/JS and Kotlin/Native could behave differently, but it would be quite surprising):

1. Structural vs non-structural:

   > > (Structural modifications are those that change the size of this list, or otherwise perturb it in such a fashion that iterations in progress may yield incorrect results.)

   "Another example would be casting the list to other type." Casting the list doesn't change it at all.
2. > What about structural changes in the returned sub-list, do they make the base list view undefined?

   No:

   > The semantics of the list returned by this method become undefined if the backing list (i.e., this list) is structurally modified **in any way other than via the returned list**.
3. > does undefined mean that changes in the base or sub-list may or may not be reflected in the corresponding views?

   This isn't directly answered, but no, it doesn't. It can e.g. throw exception on any subsequent access.